# Preprocessor macro definitions used with C function definition

Tags: c, sqlite, function, c-preprocessor

I'm studying the SQLite source code (in c), but there are some things I can't figure out what they are, and I hope you can give me a hand.
I know c, c++ and JAVA basics but I have never seen something like this and I don't know how to search for it.

In a c file, there are the next definitions (among others):

```
#ifndef SQLITE_CDECL
# define SQLITE_CDECL
#endif
#ifndef SQLITE_API
# define SQLITE_API
#endif
```

And then the above definitions are used like this:

```
SQLITE_API int SQLITE_CDECL sqlite3_conf(int, ...){
  //code
```

I know "SQLITE_API" and "SQLITE_CDECL" are not the return types, function names, keywords, K&R style nor variable modificators...

Why are this words placed like that in the function? What are they for?

Comment: It's hard to see in this example because both SQLITE_CDECL and SQLITE_API appear to "do nothing".  On some platforms, "[cdecl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)" might be needed to specify a calling sequence.  On other platforms, "[__declspec(dllimport)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271769%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)" might be needed to specify ".dll" vs .exe".  Here's an example where the Sqlite build might be configured to give both SQLITE_CDECL and SQLITE_API meaningful non-empty values: `__declspec(dllimport) void _cdecl func1(void);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two declarations look like they exist so that they can be defined differently to support certain quirks of development on Windows. Note that on the `#define` lines, they aren't defined to any value. This means that they will be replaced with nothing that the parser sees. So, `SQLITE_API int SQLITE_CDECL sqlite3_conf(int, ...){` will end up being reduced to `int sqlite3_conf(int, ...){` after the preprocessor runs. On Windows, they can be defined differently to support building DLLs with `__declspec` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75.aspx) and specifying calling conventions (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

They're used to modify the attributes of the functions on different platforms or when building certain ways. Most of the time there may be no need for them, but in certain situations they may be useful, e.g. using `__declspec(dllexport)` when building a DLL or using `static` when including the file directly instead of having the linker perform linkage between the object files.

Comment: So, if I'm getting your answer right, this words could be replaced by "static" or blank spaces (for example)?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  See also [Gnu function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) for additional, non-Microsoft examples.